# Remove newline at the end of a file in python

Tags: python, newline

I'm modifying a file with python that may already contain newlines like the following :

```
#comment
something

#new comment
something else
```

My code appends some lines to this file, I'm also writing the code that will remove what I added (ideally also working if other modifications occurred in the file).

Currently, I end up with a file that grows each time I apply the code (append/remove) with newlines characters at the end of the file.

I'm looking for a clean way to remove those newlines without too much programmatic complexity. Newlines "inside" the file should remain, newlines at the end of the file should be removed.

Comment: Change the code where you add / append the newlines such that it no longer appends newlines after the content.

Comment: @luk2302 not an option, I want my edit in this file to be separated for readability. What you're offering is a workaround which I already used, I'm trying to improve my code now.

Comment: Then read the entire file again and strip a trailing newline from the string, then write the string back to the file.

Comment: This is what I call "too much programmatic complexity", I know I can easily read the file back, keep track of a newline, keep it if some non-empty lines comes after, etc... What I'm looking for is another possible way to do it in less code lines. Since I'm new to python I might not know easy ways to achieve this like maybe a clever use of rstrip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `str.rstrip()` method:

```
my_file =  open("text.txt", "r+")
content = my_file.read()
content = content.rstrip('\n')
my_file.seek(0)

my_file.write(content)
my_file.truncate()
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for, will check soon if I can my_file.write(content) to re-write the modified content

Comment: what do you mean by "check soon"?

Comment: I just made an update on my post. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't knew about this r+ mode. thx!

Comment: Actually, I endup with two time the content of the file, 'write' is appending to the file.

Comment: Oh, right. I was so distracted. Yes wait a moment to update my code.

Comment: I've made an update. Would you check if it works?

Answer (score 2):

I needed a way to remove newline at eof without having to read the whole file into memory. The code below works for me. I find this efficient in terms of memory when dealing with large files.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f: #opens file in read/write text mode
    f.seek(0, 2) #navigates to the position at end of file 
    f.seek(f.tell() - 1) #navigates to the position of the penultimate char at end of file
    last_char = f.read() 
    if last_char == '\n':
        f.truncate(f.tell() - 1)
```